# How to store an object in input stream to a particular folder under sdcard in android?

Tags: android

I am getting an object from Amazon s3 which is assigned to input stream. I want to store that input stream object into some specified path in sdcard. That input stream object may be PDF,CSV or any other format. But i have to store all formats object into a folder under sdcard. I had tried this code

```
InputStream inputStreamReceiptObject = objectReceiptFromAmazonS3.getObjectContent();
String strReceiptPathInFolder = "/mnt/sdcard/folder1/folder2/"+objectname.extension;
```

// Where objectname.extension is as follows

// Ex : If object is PDF then pdfname.pdf

// Ex : If object is CSV then csvname.csv

```
     try {
                       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "testPdf.pdf");
                       file.createNewFile(); // Error java.io.IOException occurs in this line
                       OutputStream fOut;
                       fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
                                oos.writeObject(inputStreamReceiptObject);
                                oos.close();

                                System.out.println("added");                
//                          } 

                       } catch (Exception e) { 
                           System.out.println("ERROR "+e.toString());
                           throw new RuntimeException(e); }


I am receiving an error as "java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

// Error received in the following line 

file.createNewFile();
```

Android Manifest file i had below permissions

I want to simply store that input stream object in a folder.If object is pdf then i want to store that pdf, if csv then to store csv. But i can't able to store in a folder.Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [shouldn't](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) hard-code file paths to the sdcard.

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

However the exception occurs because you probably forgot to add the right permission to your Manifest.xml

There is [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) (which gives you read AND write permission) and if you just need read use [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Get READ and WRITE permission with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks,already i had manifest permissions. Now i removed hard coded sdcard. But i can't able to create a file sir.I had edited my question

Comment: I've tested the code and it works. If I remove the permission I get the exact same error. My guess is you haven't configured the permission correctly. Copy it from my edited answer and place it in your manifest. Make sure it's in the correct place too. Common mistakes are placing the permission tags inside the application. It has to be above or below the application tag.

Comment: Thanks, its the problem of device sdcard.And the line,File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); made to work